# Simplest possible circuit to pulldown a 12v line with delayed off? With caveats!

Tags: automotive, delay

I'm trying to pull down a low-power automotive signal that normally floats high.  The trigger is another line going high (12v brake light).  I want a delayed off of a few seconds.  The usual simple transistor/capacitor delay circuits don't really work, as the trigger line also supplies some bulbs, so the capacitor is quickly drained by those bulbs.  How can I prevent that rapid draining of C1?  Would a darlington pair help isolate that effect?

Thanks, any suggestions welcome.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFTKq7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A diode between the switch and the capacitor. Leave the lamp wiring undisturbed. That will prevent the capacitor discharging through the lamps.

Comment: For a somewhat more defined / reproducible circuit check the 555 / c555 datasheet.

Comment: You might want to beef up the 10k resistor. Right now you'll probably only get 1 second of discharge time.

Comment: @AdamHaun, With the 1 ohm bulb in parallel, the 10 kohm resistor isn't having much effect on the discharge time.

Comment: Yeah, I meant after he adds a diode. Must be more specific...

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond - if you post as an answer I will accept it.  Thanks Wouter, Adam, & Photon too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest change is a diode between the switch and the capacitor. Leave the lamp wiring undisturbed. That will prevent the capacitor discharging through the lamps.

Then, as other comments say, you can adjust the delay by changing the values of the capacitor and/or base resistor R1.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  I'm about to build this.  Don't know why my question was down-voted by someone, but I'll get over it!  Cheers.